# Cocoa - loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects: from loaded bundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nsbundle

In a document based Cocoa app, I am instantiating several objects (plugins) from external bundles using:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getPluginsOfType:(Class)type;
{
    NSBundle *main = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *allPlugins = [main pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:@"../PlugIns"];

    NSMutableArray *availablePlugins = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *path in allPlugins)
    {
    NSBundle *pluginBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    [pluginBundle load];
    Class principalClass = [pluginBundle principalClass];
    [availablePlugins addObject:principalClass];
    }
return availablePlugins;
}
```

Within each of those, a nib file is loaded upon init, which binds the root view with a property in my plugin class. Below a minimal Plugin class definition:

```
@interface Plugin

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *thePluginView;

@end

@implementation Plugin

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:self];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

While this works fine, I want to replace the above call to NSBundle (because it's deprecated for OS X 10.8+), and replace it with:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibName" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
```

However, using mainBundle in this case naturally fails to set the top level object reference in my Plugin class, I suspect cause mainBundle has nothing to do with the Plugin's bundle.

How would I go about achieving that? Is there a way to find the "current" bundle perhaps (the bundle that the Plugin class came from, so to say)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear to me exactly what you're asking - where is the "loading class" that is not in your application's bundle coming from, and what exactly do you mean by "loading class"?

Maybe the following will help:

`loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` is an instance method and loads from the bundle the instance represents.

In your sample the instance you've used you obtain via `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, so the nib is loaded from the applications main bundle.

There is no "current bundle" concept, but you can obtain an `NSBundle` instance representing other bundles, e.g. with `NSBundle`'s class method `bundleWithURL`. So to load a nib from a different bundle first create an `NSURL` that references the bundle, then create an `NSBundle` based on that, and finally load the nib.

HTH

**Addendum - After Question Updated**

From the deprecated `+loadNibName:owner:` method's description of `owner`:

> If the class of this object has an associated bundle, that bundle is searched for the specified nib file; otherwise, this method looks in the main bundle.

This is what you need to replicate when using `-loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:`. The method you need is `NSBundle`'s `bundleForClass:` which returns the `NSBundle` object that dynamically loaded a class.

So in your `Plugin` class you should be able to find the bundle it was loaded from with `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` and then call `-loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I extended the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @user2311023 - See updated answer for updated question.

Comment: Great insight from the old method! That works perfectly, many thanks.